# include string or string.h

Tags: c++

To use memset(), what is the difference between

```
#include <string>       //did not work
```

and

```
#include <string.h>     //worked
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`<string>` is a C++ standard library include, and `<string.h>` is C standard library include.

The equivalent of `<string.h>` in C++ is `<cstring>`, although both will work.

The difference is: `<cstring>` wraps everything in the `std` namespace whereas `<string.h>` puts everything in the global namespace.

Also, expect some stricter type safety rules from `<cstring>`.

Comment: What does "both work" mean? Is it "both are guaranteed to work by the standard" or "both happen to work in typical real-world environments, for [reasons]"?

Comment: Updated the answer with some extra info.

Answer (score 6):

In a modern C++ environment, you would `#include <cstring>` to get `memset()`.

Comment: Technically, You're only guaranteed `std::memset`, but all popular implementations just pull in the C header and add a `using` statement...